# Facebook SDK error iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios7, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am integrating facebook in iOS app.
Getting following errors.

**1** when i tap on close button of login window, getting error com.facebook.sdk error 2.
**Note that i dont get this error on tapping login button. I can login successfully, getting this error only when i close the login window instead of pressing login button.**

[image]

bundle identifier is added in developer account and its correct.
Searched and tried the following solutions.

[com.facebook.sdk error 2 on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159965/com-facebook-sdk-error-2-on-ios)
[Facebook SDK iOS error 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292666/facebook-sdk-ios-error-2)
[How to resolve "com.facebook.sdk error 2" under the condition that "allow these apps to use your account" is off for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006479/how-to-resolve-com-facebook-sdk-error-2-under-the-condition-that-allow-these)

**2** Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorise, fb**** is not registered as a URL Scheme. My URL scheme in plist is correct. Already tried following solutions.

[FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb**** is not registered as a URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132003/fbsdklog-cannot-use-the-facebook-app-or-safari-to-authorize-fb-is-not-regi)
[Failing to open active session after updating Facebook SDK to 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113688/failing-to-open-active-session-after-updating-facebook-sdk-to-3-5)
[Integrating Facebook SDK in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023059/integrating-facebook-sdk-in-ios)

Any other solution for both issues ??

Comment: Is the sandbox mode off for the Facebook App?

Comment: @RajanBalana - Yes, its disabled.

Comment: Have a look at this library : https://github.com/mobitar/Zuckerkit